How can I check if any number of range is between two numbers?
I'm trying to do some filter with divs. I have several divs:
<div data-areafrom="19" data-areafrom="24" class="sgmt">Div 1</div>
<div data-areafrom="30" data-areafrom="44" class="sgmt">Div 2</div>

$paramFrom = 0;
$paramTo = 20;

$('.sgmt').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('areafrom') >= $paramFrom && 
    $(this).data('areato') <= $paramTo;
}).addClass("sgmt-show");


And I need to check if any number between data-areafrom="19" and  data-areafrom="24" is between paramFrom and paramTo. How can I do that?
